# Ansible: ImportError: The requests library is not installed

Tags: python, pip, ansible

I am using Ansible 2.9.3 and python 3.6.9 and already installed openshift with pip3.

The Code looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Create a k8s namespace
    k8s:
      name: CC_Namespace
      api_version: v1
      kind: Namespace
      state: present
  # Deployment Frontend 
  - name: Create a Frontend Deployment Object
    k8s:
      apiVersion: v1 
      kind: Deployment
      metadata:
        name: nginx-frontend-deployment
        labels:
          app: nginx
      spec:
        replicas: 4
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            app: nginx
        template:
          metadata:
            labels:
              app: nginx
          spec:
            containers:
            - name: nginx
              image: nginx:1.7.9 
              ports:
              - containerPort: 80
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /ready
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /ready
...
```

and I am getting this Error:

> TASK [Create a k8s namespace]
>   ******************************************************************************************************************************************** An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full
>   traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ImportError: The requests library
>   is not installed, please install the requests package to use the
>   requests transport. fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false,
>   "error": "The requests library is not installed, please install the
>   requests package to use the requests transport.", "msg": "Failed to
>   import the required Python library (openshift) on node1's Python
>   /usr/bin/python2. Please read module documentation and install in the
>   appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but
>   Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the
>   documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}

Does anyone has an idea why the error occurs?

Comment: you forgot to ask a question- did you install the `requests` library as suggested?

Comment: yes I think it was already installed: "requests==2.18.4".

Comment: I suspect you installed ansible in python3 as well as the request module. In your playbook, you are declaring localhost as a target. Probably from [autodiscovery](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html), we can see in your error message that the python used version is 2.x. Either set `ansible_python_interpreter` to version 3 or install requests in python 2.7.

Comment: I tried this: "ansible localhost -m ping -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3' " but it's still the same error..

Comment: Your are getting a "requests library not found" error using the `ping` module ?!?!?! Moreover, read your message in more depth. What is actually missing is the `openshift` lib. Requests is just a symptom.